# Playing clips in sequence with possible interruptions from other clips (using javax.sound)

Tags: java, audio

I would like to create a simple PlayClipManager class to manage the playback of audio clips. It would have the following two methods:

```
public void addAndPlay(Clip clip)
 {
  ...
 }

public void interruptAndPlay(Clip clip)
 {
  ...
 }
```

The first method should add a clip to a queue and play it as soon as the other clips in the queue have finished. The second method accepts a clip that interrupts the current playback, flushes the queue and adds itself to it (where it plays immediately because it's the only clip in the queue).

This would be easy if one had access to the Java Thread managing audio playback, but unless I'm mistaken, I don't think there's one (there is an AudioSystem class but it is of no help for that purpose). I saw there were posts here showing how one can use a LineListener to check when a clip has finished playing, but I'm not sure how I can use that concretely in my example. Also, with the method to interrupt a clip, I guess there might also be some concurrency problems.

Any help on how I could tackle this very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, a Clip bundles the playback line with the audio data.

Do you plan to queue up actual Clips? How big are they? That can take up a LOT of memory. If you are storing the addresses of the sound files, and making/loading *new* Clips at the time of playback, you might be better off using SourceDataLine, as it will launch more quickly. A Clip has to load the entire file into memory before it can start playing.

Above is the [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html#113711) for adding a line listener. I think it is just myClip.addLineListener(YourLineListener). You can code the LineListener to alert whatever is managing the Queue to fire up the next Clip, and use this same LineListener for all the Clips.

Or maybe something like this would be helpful, call it on a new thread when you are ready to play the queue, and have the LineListener be part of the runnable that plays the Clip.

```
class PlayClipRunnable implements Runnable, LineListener {
    private Clip currentClip;
    private QueueManager queueManager;

    public PlayPadRunnable (Clip currentClip, 
            QueueManager myQueueManager) {
        this.currentClip = currentClip;
        this.myQueueManager = myQueueManager;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        try 
        {
            currentClip.addLineListener(this);
            currentClip.start();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(LineEvent event) {
        if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {

            queueManager.clipIsStopped();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about when the Clip should be opened. I'm also not sure how to put in a hook for interrupting the Clip. Maybe if the QueueManager does a currentClip.close() that will work? Having the currentClip be volatile in that case might be helpful. But I am getting out of my depth.

I hope the ideas are worth exploring and lead you to your solution.